# Which layer should create a HttpResponse?

Tags: java

Do you know why `HttpResponse` is created in the controller layer? And what will happen if `HttpResponse` is created in the service layer?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and elaborate (add more context). In general, the service layer should deal with logic and not communication protocols which the controller layer is used for. Hence creating the actual http response in the service would be unclean design. Think about what it would mean if you'd need to call that service from another part of your code that doesn't deal with http.

Comment: Nothing "happens", everything will work - but the services probably *should* not know / care about the fact that they are called via a http request.

Comment: Using layers is only a good practice that relies on *separation of concern*. If your do not care for re-useability nor testability, you can even forget about it yet write correct code. The concern of the service layer should only be the *business rules*, and it should be possible to connect it transparently to any interface. That way you can write and test it with absolutely no web framework dependancy. If you create an HttpResponse in the service layer, you bind it to the web interface and can no longer test it without that dependency.

Answer (score 2):

**HttpResponse** should not be passed to the service layer.

The Controller layer is the conductor of operations for a request. It controls the transaction scope and manages the session related information for the request. The controller first dispatches to a command and then calls the appropriate view processing logic to render the response.

also Is a best practice.